# Understanding stress tensor in a covariant way

Tags: differential-geometry, tensor-products

I am trying to understand the [stress tensor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_stress_tensor) $\sigma$ in a coordinate-free manner. Indeed, let me attempt to explain my understanding first with the [strain tensor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinitesimal_strain_theory) $\varepsilon$.

**BACKGROUND for STRAIN.** Usually, the starting point is that we have a vector function $u:\mathbb{R}^3\to\mathbb{R}^3$ which denotes the deformation $u(x)$ of the system at point $x$. It's then clear that there exists a corresponding covariant vector, i.e., $u(x) =u_i(x) dx^i$ where $u_i(x),i=1,2,3$ are the components of the vector $u(x)$ (Notice that the correspondence is canonical, i.e., coordinate-invariant). Using the Levi-Civita connection, we can then define the covariant 2-tensor $\nabla u$ in a coordinate-free manner. Indeed, this is the correct method since $(\nabla u)(\partial_i,\partial_j)=(\nabla_{\partial_j} u)(\partial_i)=\partial_j u_i$ where $\partial_i,i=1,2,3$ is the standard coordinate basis. It's then easy to see that the strain tensor $\varepsilon$ is just the symmetrization of $\nabla u$ as a covariant 2-tensor, and thus the strain tensor $\varepsilon$ has been successfully defined in a coordinate free manner.

**THOUGHTS on STRESS.** I would like to do something similar with the stress tensor $\sigma$. Indeed, usually the starting point is the stress/traction vector $T(x,\hat{n})$, which physically denotes the unit force $dF$ acting on unit surface $dS$ (with normal vector $\hat{n}$) and $x\in dS$, i.e.,
$$
T(x,\hat{n})=\frac{dF}{dS} \in \mathbb{R}^3
$$
Now let $S$ be any closed surface in $\mathbb{R}^3$. Then by Newton's law, we can appropriately assume that
$$
\oint_S T(x,\hat{n})dS=0
$$
Notice that $\hat{n} \mapsto T_x(\hat{n})$ is a mapping $\mathbb{S}^2 \to\mathbb{R}^3$. It's then easy to extend the definition to $\mathbb{R}^3\to\mathbb{R}^3$, i.e., $T_x(c\hat{n})=c\cdot T_x(\hat{n})$ for any $c>0$.
Now it seem that we can use the previous assumption to prove that $T$ is a $(1,1)$-tensor (or a covariant/contravariant 2-tensor by lowering/raising indices). Indeed, by imagining a very thin sheet, we can "formally" prove that $T(x,\hat{n})=-T(x,\hat{n})$, and by imagining a simplex as shown below, we can "formally" prove that
$$
T(x,\hat{n}) = \hat{n}_i T(x,\hat{i})
$$
The two formulas imple that $v\mapsto T(x,v)$ is linear and thus it seems that my claim is true. **SO THE QUESTION** is whether there's a more rigorous way to justify such a claim, i.e., an analogy for the covariant derivative (Levi-Civita connection), but for surfaces.

[image: simplex]